# why am i getting a syntax error on my print function

Tags: python, syntax

I have been making a program to practice math. So far everything works well, except for one print function. The print function is supposed to print the equation. Here it is:

```
print(str(NumberOne) '+' str(NumberTwo) '=' variable)
```

When i try to run the program it gives me a syntax error normally pointing to the single quote after the + sign. I cannot see why this continues to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by other answers, there is no operator to combine the given expressions.  You can use plus signs to perform string concatenation, or can use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to accomplish this without all the `+` signs:

```
print("%s+%s=%s" % (NumberOne,NumberTwo,variable))
```

Or, use the `format` method:

```
print( "{0}+{1}={2}".format(NumberOne, NumberTwo, variable) )
```

Comment: Besides being more readable, and giving better error messages when you get things wrong, it also avoids the extra `str` calls—you can pass an int or a float or a list of numpy arrays to `%` or `format` and it'll find some way to print it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `+` to explicitly concatenate the strings:

```
print(str(NumberOne) + '+' + str(NumberTwo) + '=' + variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing commas between your arguments,

Try:

```
print(str(NumberOne), '+', str(NumberTwo), '=', variable)
```

Comment: Or, more likely, he intended `+` operators. Otherwise, he wouldn't call `str` on everything.

Comment: @abarnert I think he wanted to show the result of a calculation: that NumberOne plus NumberTwo equals Variable.

Comment: Yes, like `3+4=x`. The fact that he's calling `str` on those `Number1` and `NumberTwo` implies that he has, say, ints, and needs them as strings, presumably to concatenate them. (It's not that unreasonable for a novice to not understand why `"1" "2"` concatenates to `"12"` but after `str(1) "2"` doesn't, is it?) Of course it's also possible that he's calling `str` for absolutely no reason, having copied and pasted from some code that he didn't understand at all that isn't relevant here, but I wouldn't want to assume that without cause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the string with + operator

```
print(str(NumberOne) + '+' + str(NumberTwo) + '=' + variable)
```